# "tab" key event as "enter" key event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` which takes a number. I need to use "tab" key event same like "enter" key event.

```
    JLabel lblPieChart = new JLabel("Maximum pie chart label length:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    basePanel.add(lblPieChart, gbc);

    // PieChart Label textbox
    SwiftApplication APP = SwiftApplication.getInstance();
    int nMaxLabel = APP.getMaxPieLabel();
    mMaxLabelLength = new JTextField();
    mMaxLabelLength.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 24));
    mMaxLabelLength.setText(new Integer(nMaxLabel).toString());
    GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    basePanel.add(mMaxLabelLength, gbc2);
    mMaxLabelLength.addActionListener(this);
```

In above code, as soon as I press enter after entering a number, the `ActionListener` comes into play and does the calculation using the number. I need to do the same thing, if I press "tab". Currently, if I press tab, it goes to next text field without any change.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a FocusListener or InputVerifier (if you want to verify input).

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)